# HTTP URL redirect status code

Tags: java

The url which I give gets redirected. When i hit the url with some browser it redirects to another site. When i test it in some rest client i am getting http code 302, which is correct for redirect. But i try the same with below code, it returns 200. Can somebody help me out ?Thanks in advance.
updated url.

```
    try {
     URL url = new URL("https://securestore.hbo.com/cart.php?f=pplogin&amp;ppx=1&amp;method=checkout");
     HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     connection.connect();
     int code = connection.getResponseCode();
     System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
     System.out.println("code is" + code);
     connection.disconnect();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStacTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If url1 is being redirected to url2, then you will get 302 status. However if you code is directally calling url2, you are bound to get 200.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
.....
connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

The HttpURLConnection will follow the redirects by default.

Try setting the following if you do not wish to follow redirects:

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

For example, in relation to your code:

```
try {
     URL url = new URL("");
     HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
     HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     connection.connect();
     int code = connection.getResponseCode();
     System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
     System.out.println("code is" + code);
     connection.disconnect();
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStacTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Comment: Already tried HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);, but it was helpless :(

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to make sure that the HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false); is set prior to instantiating a connection object. Otherwise, try connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a response with the 302 code you want. Something like `connection.setStatus(statusCode)` I may be wrong though.